# jQuery AJAX not sending to my PHP program

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm no expert in AJAX (or jQuery) but I thought what I was doing was pretty easy yet when I send an ajax request with:

```
$.ajax ( requestObj );
```

it doesn't send and I'm hoping someone can help. In order to give context, I've set the "requestObj" up as follows:

```
    //initialise a request object
    var requestObj = {};
    requestObj.response = 'ajax-response';
    requestObj.type = 'POST';
    requestObj.url =  my_config['ajax-service-list'][service]['url'];
    requestObj.data = $.extend ( requestObj.data , {
                                            action: service,
                                            other: parameters,
                                            _ajax_nonce: my_config['ajax-service-list'][service]['nonce']
    });
    requestObj.global = false;
    requestObj.timeout = 30000;
    requestObj.success = function ( r ) {
        alert ( "Success: " + r );
    }
    requestObj.error = function ( r ) {
        console.log ("FAILURE WITH AJAX Call ( " + JSON.stringify (r) + ")");
    }
```

There's one thing that probably needs explaining. The two references to "my_config" are references to a Javascript variable that I set using Wordpress's wp_localize_script() function. Basically it just provides context about where to find the URL, the NONCE to use, etc. I have tested that the URL and NONCE information is working correctly so that shouldn't be the problem. For example, I put a breakpoint on the browsers debugger on the line after the two references are defined and got these results:
[image: debugger output of requestObj properties]

When I call the ajax function it immediately executes the success function and sends in the value of 0. Looking at my PHP error logs though I can see that the request was never sent. What could be getting in the way of $.ajax(requestOb) from actually sending the request?

UPDATE:

Thanks to Michael's sage advice I realised that I am in fact getting a request to go out but as it's running in a local environment the response is coming back lightening fast. Now I am suspecting this has more to with Wordpress configuration. I have hooked into the wp_ajax_[service_name] but it immediately returns 0. I'll re-ask this question with this new information in the wordpress forum.

Comment: You should be using a browser inspector to detect if an ajax request is made. Open up the network tab of any inspector, and you can watch requests as they happen. How is the $.ajax() method being instantiated? You may have an issue with that, as opposed to $.ajax().

Comment: As much as I love the debugger I've never used the "network" tab. Looking at it now it looks like a treasure mine!

Comment: Mathew, I wish I could mark your comment as correct as it has been invaluable. I can see now that I am indeed sending the request but getting back a very quick response (and with no log message).

Comment: What is the HTTP response code? My bet is you have a syntax error or something in your php controller...

Comment: The status code is 200. I've run textmate's syntax validator and it claims there's no errors; not perfect but I've found it be a very good judge.

Comment: See my answer. You should now var_dump($_REQUEST) to see if the controller is receiving the data (you can see the output in your browser inspector). If the data transfer is good, you need to start debugging your controller script... Probably worth making a new question, as you know your ajax isn't at fault now.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a browser inspector to detect if an ajax request is made. Open up the network tab of any inspector, and you can watch requests as they happen. How is the $.ajax() method being instantiated? You may have an issue with that, as opposed to $.ajax().

Once you've used the inspector, look at the $_POST or $_GET data you're sending in the headers section, and then look at the response. Is the HTTP response code 200? If it's 500, then you probably have an error in your PHP controller that receives the request.

If you have PHP CLI, run this to see if you have a syntax error:

```
php -l path/to/php/controller.php
```

If you have a non-fatal error in your file, you'll see the error output in the request response.

Try var_dump( $_REQUEST ) at the top of your php file, too, to make sure that the file is receiving the data, and you can inspect it inside the browser-inspector response.

If you have a problem with the program inside of your controller... you've got yourself a new question to post. :)

Comment: have you tried var_dump($_REQUEST) in the php controller, then inspecting the response?

Comment: just trying to decide WHERE to put it. it never calls my hooked functions but it does call the add_listeners() method which sets up the hook so assuming that's the best place.

Comment: Okay, I would do two things. Just assign requestObj.data a normal object literal, instead of using $.extend. Then add requestObj.dataType = 'json' and see what the output is.

Comment: Ok, i've put it at the top of the file and run the AJAX. Now I understand what you wanted to test. The results are very interesting. It does seem that it's calling some of my hook functions.

Comment: Sounds like you need to post another question that shows your controller script. :) $.ajax() mystery solved!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16448/discussion-between-ken-and-matthew-blancarte)

Answer (score 0):

At first look, it looks like your URL has spaces around `get_action_template`. That might be an issue.

Also, passing `dataType` might help.

If not try getting a JSON response without any parameters and post the output

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've answered this damn question finally. Arrgh. BIG, BIG THANKS to Mathew to who's troubleshooting skills I could not have done without. Anyway, the problem was in the AJAX request and as a result the Wordpress Ajax manager was never respecting the "hooks" I had put into place on the PHP side.

How was my AJAX request off? I had a POST request but the URL had GET variables hanging off of it. The key variable for Wordpress based Ajax requests is the "action" variable. This is the variable which WP's ajax manager uses to distinguish the various services and is the name that you'll be hooking into.

So in the end, my URL was:

```
 http://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

and my POST variables included:

```
action: get-action-template
```

My wordpress hook is:

```
add_action ( 'wp_ajax_get-action-template' , 'AjaxServiceManager::ajax_handler' );
```

My sleepless nights may continue but they won't be related to this damn problem anymore. :^)